# Having trouble matching a single character in an SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I need to use the '_' wildcard to find all id that are only one letter which there are a few of. However when I run my query no rows are returned.

Heres my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id LIKE '_';
```

I have a table lets call Table1 that has two columns, id and name.
id either has 1 or 2 characters to label a name. I'm trying to only find the names where the id is only one character. Heres an example of the table:

```
id     name
A      Alfred
AD     Andy
B      Bob
BC     Bridget
```

I only want to return Alfred and Bob in this example.

I don't want the solution but any advice or ideas would be helpful.

Here is a screenshot of my query:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2mCt.png

And here is a small example of my table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/APInZ.png

So in this example of my table I would ideally like only East Asia... to be returned.

I if I search specifically for the character it works but for some strange reason the '_' wildcard doesn't.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM icao
WHERE prefix_code ='Z';
```

This works.

Comment: provide some sample data.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(id) = 1` should do the trick, no?

Comment: My Professor actually wants us to use the '_' wildcard specifically for this example but thanks though!

Comment: @JNevill Can you post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: So... interesting that `LIKE '_'` should work, but doesn't. When I run your SQL through sqlfiddle, it works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d0096/1

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10` to make sure your table has data and you've got a proper connection. If the sample data you provided is accurate, your query as it is should return 2 rows.

Comment: OP, your query works. Did you even try it?

Comment: Perhaps you have some whitespace hanging out in your `ID` field?

Comment: Its actually not working on my machine which is super strange. I'll try posting a screenshot of my query and it not working.

Comment: Please do, because I have no problems in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @JNevill That's what I was thinking unfortunately. Is there a way to check if theres whitespace? Thanks for all the help by the way

Comment: I just did a check on that last sqlfiddle I posted and added whitespace. MySQL didn't care and still returned the expected results o_0   So much for that idea.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/668b1d/2

Comment: @McAdam331 I just tried posting my screenshots put I don't have 10 reputation yet unfortunately lol

Comment: @that_guy_mcp you could upload to Imgur and post the link in a comment?

Comment: @McAdam331 Good idea I'll do that now

Comment: Maybe drop and add the table again?

Comment: @McAdam331 I just edited my post with the screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: @that_guy_mcp as far as white space is concerned, you could try using [TRIM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) on the id column? I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the underscore is used to represent a wildcard for a single character. You can read more about that [Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) here.

The way you have it written, your query will pull any rows where the id column is just one single character, you don't need to change anything.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/012d7/4) example.

**EDIT**

One trouble shooting tip is to be sure there is no whitespace before/after the prefix code. If there is, and you need to remove it, add TRIM():

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE TRIM(id) LIKE '_';
```

Here is an example with [TRIM](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2eb/2).

**EDIT 2**

A little explanation to your weird behavior, hopefully. In MySQL, if there is trailing white space on a character, it will still match if you say `id = 'Z';` as seen by [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad832/2) fiddle now. However, leading white space will not match this, but will still be corrected by TRIM(), because that removes white space on the front and back end of the varchar.

TL;DR You have trailing white space after Z and that's causing the problem.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help out. Very strange that `= 'z';` works, and so does this, but if it works it works, right? ;P

Comment: @that_guy_mcp it looks like the problem was because you have white space *after* the Z. See my edit, and the other fiddle example.

Comment: Also, I've compiled everything I said into **one** fiddle, if it clears things up. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44057/1

Comment: Ah, that may actually be the problem haha. Still kinda new to this whole thing. Honestly thanks for all the help with this. I'm gonna make a few adjustments to my table now

Comment: @that_guy_mcp out of curiosity, try doing `SELECT LENGTH(id) FROM myTable WHERE id = 'Z';` and see how many characters really are in that cell?

Comment: I got 2 haha so I guess there really is hidden white space. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using TRIM

```
Select *
FROM [Table]
where TRIM(ID) LIKE '_';
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for the behavior you observe is trailing spaces (or other whitespace) in the value.  That is, you see one character

```
'A'
```

But the value may actually be stored as two (or more) characters.

```
'A '
```

To see what's actually stored, you can use the `HEX` and `LENGTH` functions.

```
SELECT t.foo
     , LENGTH(t.foo)
     , HEX(t.foo)
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.foo LIKE 'A%'
```

The `%` is a wildcard for the `LIKE` operator that matches any number of characters (zero, one or more).

You can use the `RTRIM()` function to remove trailing spaces...

```
SELECT RTRIM(t.foo)
     , LENGTH(RTRIM(t.foo))
     , HEX(RTRIM(t.foo))
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.foo LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: You noticed this at about the same time I did. Do you know why MySQL still returned a row when OP says 'id = 'A';'?

Comment: @McAdam331: because the comparison semantics used by the equality comparison (`=`) is different from the semantics used by `LIKE`.  The difference is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual here: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(id)=1
```

Comment: My Professor actually wants us to use the '_' wildcard specifically for this example

Answer (score 0):

Strange..., in my case works perfectly (I am using mysql 5.5).
Please, try this:

```
select * from mysql.help_topic where name like '_';
```

What set you get?