# MySQL return empty result when use Like "ABC%" construction

Tags: php, mysql

I use
MySQL 5.1.4, with utf8_general_ci

I have a correct answer when I use query

```
SELECT code, searchString FROM places WHERE searchString LIKE "%45%" LIMIT 15
```

or

```
SELECT code, searchString FROM places WHERE searchString LIKE "%km" LIMIT 15
```

But when I use query

```
SELECT code, searchString FROM places WHERE searchString LIKE "45%" LIMIT 15
```

I have response from mysql: MySQL returned an empty result set.

My table contain values with leading simbols "45xxx"

```
"43014000" "745 km"
"50022000" "Base N 45"
"54008000" "45 km"
```

How  I can fix that?

**Upd.: p.s.** The problem initially occurred due to incorrect import from an external file

Comment: I'm confused. Which of the three queries returned that result set?

Comment: Are you positive there are no leading spaces (or other semi-visible or invisible characters) before the "45"?

Comment: Uueerdo - I don't see any leading spaces. How I can check for invisible characters before the "45"?

Comment: @OlegUshakov as mentioned beneath my answer, you can try by using the `LENGTH()` function.

Comment: @OlegUshakov you could use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that there is some leading white space in that column that is not shown when you run a select query, I have seen some problems like this before.

As a work around, you can `TRIM()` the column, which will remove leading white space, and then do your search:

```
SELECT code, searchString
FROM myTable
WHERE TRIM(searchString) LIKE '45%'
LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: If you want to verify whether or not there is leading white space, you can run a query that does `SELECT LENGTH(searchString)` and compare that length to what you actually expect.

Comment: Hmm, I have the same problem on a various queries. I Try you code - empty result.

Comment: @OlegUshakov there is a similar issue that I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975260/having-trouble-matching-a-single-character-in-an-sql-table/29975431#29975431), see if anything like that may be related.

Comment: You could also try `REPLACE(searchString, " ", "")` and see if that works, instead of TRIM.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is solving

```
SELECT code, searchString FROM places WHERE searchString LIKE "_45%" LIMIT 15
```

return correct result

Comment: This means there is one character before the 45, probably a leading white space.

Comment: Yes, but is not a space character. It seems it a special characters in the source data has been imported in database.